# Python Pandas "List comprehension"

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to filter a column based on a conditional, in this simple case:

`y = pd.DataFrame({'abc': [1,2,3,4], 'def': [5,6,7,8]})`

I want to filter 'abc' so that only values under 4 are displayed, and only by using square brackets, not df.loc, numpy or any other method.

I have attempted to mess around with square brackets and where the if condition should be applied, such as:

`y['abc'] = [[y['abc']][y['abc'] = y['abc'] <4]]`

(Note: this gives an error, im aware its not correct.)

`y['abc'] = y['abc'] < 4`

This code returns the booleans, but i instead want the values.

I have made it work before, but sadly the HDD my files were in was corrupted, and i cant find the correct link now.

Comment: Maybe `c = y['abc'][y['abc'] < 4]` is what you want?

Comment: Gives me an error sadly (i think you also have one square bracket too much).
i made it work by copying the dataframe with:

z = y[(y['abc'] < 4)]

but i instead want to override the original dataframe instead of just copying, as that will easily create a lot of needless variables.

Comment: Which error? For me it works. `print(c)` shows the expected part of the series `y['abc']`.

Comment: If you just want to avoid additional variables (which may or may not be a good idea), use `y = y[y['abc'] < 4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'abc': [1,2,3,4], 'def': [5,6,7,8]})
df = df[df['abc'] < 4]
```

Answer (score -2):

You're almost there.

If you pass your booleans to the dataframe, you'll get your desired filtered output:

```
y = pd.DataFrame({'abc': [1,2,3,4], 'def': [5,6,7,8]})
y = y[y['abc'] is y['abc'] < 4]
```

However, note the 'is' instead of '=='!

Comment: Sorry but this is nonsense. The `is` operator will just result in `False` here and `y[False]` is useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I also got this solution to work in the meantime:

y['abc'][(y['abc'] < 4)]

Just leaving it for posterity in case someone else needs an alternate solution. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Atlas you accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: Reading it again now, I have to admit that this is not really optimal. It does yield the right result though.
@Paulo Coelho Kotchetkoff 's answer would be the one to accept